# Shelly Plug S with iobroker per MQTT no Acknowledged when Relay0.Switch is changed

Tags: mqtt, shelly

if i set switch from false to true the relais switches on but the state of the switch will reset back to false after few seconds.

To switch the relais off via iobroker i have to switch it on and off immediately after in the timeframe were switch is still on true.

When writing the value and tick the Acknowledged checkbox from the iobroker admin webside the switch will stay at true. But thats not a solution for me.

Changing the state of the switch via the shelly webinterface doesnt change anything in the iobroker.

All things are up to date
Communication via MQTT on all devices.
iobroker js-controller 4.0.23
Shelly Plugin 6.0.0
Shelly Plug 20190516-073020/master@ea1b23db and it tells me there is no newer available.

Other Shellys like Shelly Flood, Shelly RGBW2 or Shelly Uni work without problems.

Factory Reset did not help. I have only one of the plugs but want to order more if the problem can be fixed.

thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Forced a Firmware upgrade with
http://archive.shelly-tools.de/ to the newest version fixed the issue.